# Web.config file path declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, log4net

I cant get to write to log files from web.config. I recently added log4net in to project and it works fine but path declaration is failing. When I give the local path it works fine but when I give the generalized path it fails.

`Local Path:<file value="C://Users//abcd//Source//Repos//project2//sol//sol.logic//sol.logic//Logs//Log4net.txt" />`

Generalized Path: "~sol//sol.logic//sol.logic//Logs//Log4net.txt" />

Thanks

Comment: I'd begin by trying your path starting with just `//`, `~/`, `sol//` or `/sol//`.  Also, when you say it fails, where are you expecting it to log to? - because I imagine it will log relative to your output directory

Comment: Im trying to log it to a text file that I created inside the proj. in the Logs folder. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In web.config file,
Maybe you can try this:

```
<appSettings> add key="LOGS" value="~sol\sol.logic\sol.logic\Logs\" /></appSettings>
```

Comment: In this case, it's not app settings thats need tobe changed, im trying to customize config file provided by log$net, it has "file value" for path declaration.